# Apache Camel - How to catch Exception with Multicast?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've a main route in my app, called MAIN_ROUTE.
I've implemented a multicast pattern in a sub-route (called SOME_ROUTE), in order to call some other endpoints sequentially, individually.

Here's main route's code :

```
onException(Exception.class)
    //Do some stuff here
    .end();

from(MAIN_ROUTE)
    //do some stuff, no specific config
    .to(SUB_ROUTE)
    .end();
```

Here's the called route code :

```
from(SUB_ROUTE)
        .routeId(SUB_ROUTE)
        .streamCaching()
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "ExchangeId : $simple{id} - Start route")
        .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
            //We use a multicast because we need to call initialization route and we don't care about the exchange body of that route
        .multicast()
            .stopOnException()
            .to(SOME_ENDPOINT_1, SOME_ENDPOINT_2)
        .end()
    .end();
```

I want to catch & manage any exceptions raised in multicast on that top-level route.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have a "shareUnitOfWork" attribute (whose default is false) on the multicast pattern.
Basically: if enabled, it makes your main Camel Exchange sharing the same working context as the created sub-exchanges; in particular any exception occurring inside the multicast will be propagated to the parent exchange.